# Animate.css animation fadeInDown stopped working after adding @angular/material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, animate.css

I recently added angular material to my angular project, but soon after adding @angular/material to my project some of the animations provided by animate.js stopped working.

Is there any way that i can keep both animate.js and angular material working together.

Console error:

```
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js'
```

but i do have that file at that path.

Comment: remove node_modules and try to re-install a fresh copy again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that'll help: ( in order to disable angular material animations in conflicted areas)

-use `NoopAnimationsModule` instead `BrowserAnimationsModule` to disable all animations

-use `@HostBinding('@.disabled') private disabled = true;` to disable a component animations

-use `<mat-checkbox @.disabled></mat-checkbox>` to disable a material component (using directive)